# How to optimize the following symbolic expression in sympy

Tags: python, sympy, simplification

I want to simplify a computation based on C, and D using `sympy`. However, I dont know how to simplify/subs,... `C*DT` by `G`. For instance, `C(i,0)*DT(0,j)+C(i,1)*DT(1,j)` must be replaced by `G(i,j)`, i.e., `G=C*DT`. This replacement must be applied as much as possible.

My code:

```
import sympy
from sympy import *

n, m = 4, 2

C = sympy.Matrix(n, m, lambda i, j: sympy.var('C%d_%d' % (i, j)))
D = sympy.Matrix(n, m, lambda i, j: sympy.var('D%d_%d' % (i, j)))


DT = D.transpose()

CDT = C * DT

G = sympy.Matrix(n, n, lambda i, j: sympy.var('G%d_%d' % (i, j)))

# does not work, no change in CDT
# CDT.subs(CDT,G)
```